# How does &= work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This scenario seems to work as expected (where `a &= b;` is equiv. to `a = a && b`), but I'm not confident in its usage because I haven't seen it used in many places. Scenario:

```
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
a &= b;
console.log(a); // 0
a = 1;
a &= b;
console.log(b); // 1
```

But what is going on here?

```
var a = 11011;
var b = 11101;
a &= b;
console.log(a); // 11009
```

Comment: `a &= b` is equivalent to `a = a & b`.

Comment: 110011 &= 110000 ->   110000   Bitwise, friend.

Comment: ah, bitwise makes sense. is this documented (I'd like to see the implementation to feel a little better about it)? also, is there an `&&=`?

Comment: "Is this documented", of course it is -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: You're sure you're not just looking for `+=`

Comment: @j08691 - thanks for referring me to the previous question. Just wondering, does anyone know how the "This question may already have an answer here:..." is populated at the top of my question? I always thought it was an edit, but it looks like it's automatically generated.

Comment: It gets there when we decide to close the question.

Comment: You should accept an answer below anyway, as there are some good answers posted.

Comment: Where can I find the source for the &= implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will make it obvious how the [bitwise &](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.26_%28Bitwise_AND%29) works :

```
(11011).toString(2) -> "10101100000011"
(11101).toString(2) -> "10101101011101"
(11009).toString(2) -> "10101100000001"
```

The third number, in binary writing, has `1` exactly where the two other numbers had `1`.

Answer (score 3):

`&=` stands for shorthand bitwise AND operator.

```
a &= b;
```

It does bitwise AND of `a` and `b` and the result will be stored back in `a`.

And `a & b` is NOT equivalent to `a && b`. The former is a bitwise operator while the later is a logical operator.

```
11011 -> 10101100000011
11101 -> 10101101011101
-----------------------
11009 -> 10101100000001
```

Answer (score 2):

in JavaScript (as with other C-like languages) the & operator is for bitwise AND (similar to logical and && but operates on each bit of a number)

So a &= b is actually:
a = a & b;

NOT:
a = a && b;

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question

```
var a = 11011;
var b = 11101;
a &= b;
console.log(a); // 11009
```

What you are bitwising is `11011` base `10` to `11101` base `10`.

If you want to bitwise `a` and `b`, you can do it this way:

```
var a = parseInt(11011, 2);
var b = parseInt(11101, 2);
a &= b;
console.log(parseInt(parseInt(a, 10).toString(2)));
```